# Galaxy watch wont connect to Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-gear

So I have made my first app and it runs great on the emulator, but now I want to deploy it to my physical device.

I have enabled bluetooth and connected the WiFi of the watch to the same WiFi access point as my computer. I have also enabled debugging. But every time I try to connect I get this error message. If I hit the scan button in Tizen studio, nothing is found and if I specify the IP directly it fails to connect.

I have tried this on 3 different WiFi access points. 
I have also allowed the port 26101 on TCP and UDP through my local firewall.

[image]

I am not sure why this wont work. Is there a setting somewhere I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. I forgot to enable debug on the watch and to reboot the watch. here is a good tutorial that covers setting up the cert with the DUID [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3WfngRvOSM&t=1355s)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix is to install `Samsung Certificate Extension` as shown in this screenshot 
[image]

After this you need to pick Samsung when you create a new certificate and it should all work fine from there.

Comment: No. That is not the fix. This happens after the certificate extensions has already been installed.

Comment: Well in my situation that was the fix. Also ended up contacting Samsung and they also said that was the fix

Comment: I cannot connect to my gear sport after updating to 4.0. Is anyone encountering the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting it. That normally fixes the issue if you have this installed

Comment: I have restarted it. I have the cert manager installed, I can ping to the watch, and a port scanner I got on my comptuer shows it can see the port is reachable. but it still will fail to connect.